# How to console.table(array) ONLY display array elements, not methods (Ember Array)

Tags: javascript, arrays, ember.js, console.log

Preface: Dealing with an Ember.js Array

Been testing out console.table. Seems handy. However, it's annoying to see the array's methods in the output as well:

[image]

I'm repeatedly printing this out to visually sanity check a comparator function.

How can I console.table ONLY the array elements?

Comment: It looks like you're using some framework that adds more functions to your arrays. Since your arrays seems to have a `_super` property maybe they're not actually `Array`s but a subclass? Does that framework use the `prototype` property?

Comment: ! sounds suspect! I am using Ember, tho I'm not explicitly using an Ember ArrayProxy (that I know of)... hmmmm good line of inquiry. lemme see if i can find out if it's a frd Array or a Ember fancy pants Array

Comment: Verified, Ember magic is happening here. Changing question title / tags.

Comment: `console.table` was probably not written with this in mind. You can always write a function that turns a magic array back into a normal array, to print it. `var normal = Array.prototype.slice.call(magic_array, 0)` works I think.

Comment: dang, var normal = Array.prototype.slice.call(magic_array, 0) doesn't work either. ember is catching it somewhere. i'm thinking bout closing question as "nope, not possible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible unless you turn off Ember Array Extensions

(afaict)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tty-table](https://github.com/tecfu/tty-table) to accomplish this in the console - and filter out unwanted array elements using the **formatter** option.